# TypeLoadException: Type 'Castle.Proxies.IComponentProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface

Tags: c#, autofac, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I would like to log the calling of user interface methods.

My idea is to intercept the MyUserInterface class which inherits from System.Windows.Forms.Form.

However, I got TypeLoadException: Type 'Castle.Proxies.IComponentProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface

How to solve this issue?

Am I missing something on registration?

Thank you!

[I also save the code on fiddle. You can try to run.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/POCbdQ)

```cs
using System;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();      
        builder.RegisterType<MyInterceptor>();
        builder.RegisterType<MyUserInterface>().As<IMyUserInteraface>()
            .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
            .InterceptedBy(typeof(MyInterceptor));          

        var container = builder.Build();
        var ui = container.Resolve<IMyUserInteraface>();
        ui.Show();
    }       
}
public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UI intercepted and logged");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}
//If MyUserInterface inherit Form, will get TypeLoadException.
//TypeLoadException: Type 'Castle.Proxies.IComponentProxy' from assembly 'DynamicProxyGenAssembly2, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is attempting to implement an inaccessible interface.
//public class MyUserInterface : Form, IMyUserInteraface
public class MyUserInterface : IMyUserInteraface
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Show something");
    }
}
public interface IMyUserInteraface
{
    void Show();
}
```

I had tried to remove inheritance Form. Then it works.
But MyUserInterface have to inherit from Form.

Comment: Type interception - driven by Castle.Core - is pretty complex. [Make sure you read the docs a couple times through.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html) It's going to try to generate a "wrapper" class to proxy to the type underneath - that's how interception works. If it can't wrap something, you'll get errors like this. Search for answers mostly in Castle; this won't be an Autofac thing, Autofac just helps you wire up Castle.

Answer (score 0):

[Code here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pY58cV)

For now, solved by using CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget in ProxyGenerator.

```cs
using System;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extras.DynamicProxy;
using Castle.DynamicProxy;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        //builder.RegisterType<MyInterceptor>();
        //builder.RegisterType<MyUserInterface>().As<IMyUserInteraface>()
        //    .EnableInterfaceInterceptors()
        //    .InterceptedBy(typeof(MyInterceptor));

        var generator = new ProxyGenerator();
        var myUserInterface = new MyUserInterface();
        var userInterfaceProxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget<IMyUserInteraface>(myUserInterface, new MyInterceptor());

        builder.RegisterInstance(userInterfaceProxy).As<IMyUserInteraface>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        var ui = container.Resolve<IMyUserInteraface>();
        ui.Run();
    }
}
public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("UI intercepted and logged");
        invocation.Proceed();
    }
}

public class MyUserInterface : Form, IMyUserInteraface
{
    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Show something");
    }
}
public interface IMyUserInteraface
{
    void Run();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**